# How to specify the table name in hibernate criteria Projections.sqlGroupProjection

Tags: group-by, projection, hibernate-criteria

I want to use group by to field called "created_on" in hibernate criteria. I have joined 2 tables and both tables are having "created_on" field. How can I specify the field name with table name in sqlGroupProjection in hibernate criteria.

```
    Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Receipt.class, "rec");
    criteria.createAlias("rec.Invoice", "inv", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
    proList.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date(created_on) as createdOn", "createdOn", new String[] { "createdOn" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }));

    criteria.setProjection(proList);
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to use  the alias **{alias}** , your code will be   :

```
 Criteria criteria = getSession().createCriteria(Receipt.class, "rec");
    criteria.createAlias("rec.Invoice", "inv", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN);
    ProjectionList proList = Projections.projectionList();
    proList.add(Projections.sqlGroupProjection("date({alias}.created_on) as createdOn", "createdOn", new String[] { "createdOn" }, new Type[] { StandardBasicTypes.DATE }));

    criteria.setProjection(proList);
```